# FFmpeg Slideshow issues

Tags: ffmpeg

trying to get my head around ffmpeg to create a slideshow where each image is displayed for ~5 seconds with some audio. created a bat file to run the following so far:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i image-%%03d.jpg -i music.mp3 output.mpg
```

It gets the images and displayes them all very fast in the first second of the video, it then plays out the rest of the audio while showing the last image.

I want to make the images stay up longer (about 5 seconds), and stop the video after the last frame (not playing the rest of the song), are either of these things possible? i could hack the frame rate thing i guess by having hundreds of the same image in order to keep it up longer, but this is far from ideal!

Thanks

Comment: try adding switch "-r .2" for a framerate of one every 5 seconds

Comment: Next time you should ask ffmpeg command-line usage questions at [su] because Stack Overflow is specific to programming. Your question may be migrated automatically so please do not crosspost the same question to other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Sorry i was unaware of that, i will do that from now on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default encoder for mpg output, `mpeg1video`, is strict about the allowed frame rates, so an input and an output `-r` are required:

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i image-%03d.jpg -i music.mp3 -r 25 -qscale:v 2 -shortest -codec:a copy output.mpg
```

The input images will have a frame rate of 1 frame every 5 seconds and the output will duplicate frames to reach 25 frames per second.

- `-f image2` is generally not required.
- `-qscale:v` can control output quality. A sane range is 2-5.
- `-shortest` will make the output duration the same as the shortest input duration.
- `-codec:a copy` copy your MP3 audio instead of re-encoding.

MPEG-1 video has more modern alternatives. See the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for more info.

Also see:
* [FFmpeg FAQ: How do I encode single pictures into movies?](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f)
* [FFmpeg Wiki: Create a video slideshow from images](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)

Comment: Thanks very much, it does not quite work for me but it is much closer! -shortest is amazing. It is for some reason only using the first 3 images if you have any idea why?

Comment: Never mind its been a long day and i made a slight typo! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the filter fps instead of output framerate

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i img%03d.png -i musicfile -c:v libx264 -vf fps=25 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

This however skips the last image for me strangely.